# Write metadata to mp3 file in python without using external module

Tags: python

Currently am trying to `read and write` mp3 tags **without** using any external modules like(eyed3).

I have successfully read the audio tags of a mp3 file using the following code:

```
f = open(filepath,"rb")
f.seek(-128,2)
TagContent = f.read(128)
f.close()

title = TagContent[3:33] # currently only id3v1 tags
```

Now I want to edit the audio tags like `artistname,title,album` etc of a mp3 file. Now the problem am facing is how to write data to a mp3 file that too at a specific position.

```
f = open(filepath,"wb")
f.write(**what should come here**)
```

Is this possible using only python or I have to use an `external module` to write content to a mp3 file.

In the above statement `external module` refers to modules like `pymedia` or `GST-Python`(*I don't even know whether these are the right modules for this task*) not audio tagging modules like eyed3.

PS: This is just part of a learning process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use seek for select position and write, to write text from this position. Don't forget close file :)